# Angular Directive, cannot attach event listener to element

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I try to bind a `keyup` event to an input element inside an attribute directive.
I've tried normal ways like `element.nativeElement.onkeyup` or `element.nativeElement.addEventListener('keyup', () => {})` but when I type, nothing happens.

Now, I try using `HostListener` writing code like this

```
@HostListener('keyup', ['$event']) onKeyup(e) {}
```

**UPDATE**

Turns out, @HostListener has to be top level to work. But still, nothing happens when I type on the input. Here's the full code for the directive.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appKeyUp]'
})
export class KeyUpDirective implements OnInit {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('directive initiated');
    }
    @HostListener('keyup', [$event]) onKeyUp(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

What is going wrong this time?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zldrbj

Comment: If you are still having issues, please post all your code for the directive you've written. The more information the better

Comment: Is the directive correctly declared in the same module as the component you are using it in? Or maybe you forgot to export the directive?

Comment: Actually, it is declared and exported on a shared module I use across the app which has multiple lazy loaded modules. I've verified it 3 times just to be sure.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine if you have marked the directive in correct place and also have enclosed $event with `["$event"]`. please provide a [mcve], best would be a stackblitz.

Comment: It works now. I'm so exhausted, I was testing on the wrong input . Thanks for your time anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a directive for the keypress event:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[app-key-press]"
})
export class KeyupDirective {
  @HostListener("keyup", ["$event"]) onKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

And use it on the input:

```
<input type="text" app-key-press />
```

That's all you need. Don't bind the event using `element.nativeElement.onkeyup`. All you need is to use the directive selector on the input.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have already tried that  and as I mentioned on the question, it gives the following error. `Cannot find the name 'onKeyup'. Did you mean 'onkeyup'?`

Comment: @Buu97 Use `onKeyUp`